# Unity IAP Iphone 6

Tags: unity3d

Eu estou usando o SIS eo OpenIAB na minha loja, ao testar no iphone 5 ios 8.1.3 tudo ok. Ao enviar para a apple eles rejeitao o app dizendo que quando você clica no buy não acontece nada (isso no iphone 6). O openIAB já é compatível com iphone6? Ou o problema é outra coisa?

Comment: Este é o site em Português. Portante as perguntas devem ser em Português.

Comment: resolvido muito obg pela ajuda